# Django: keep data visible in multiple individual forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have three forms in three tabs respectively in a template.

I fill in the first tab, submit, fill in the second form, submit, fill in the third form, submit.

Is there a way to keep the data in each form after saving? I need to show them all together.

No, when I save the second form I lose my data on the first form.

**input.html**: template

```
<form class="tab-pane fade in active" id="demographics" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="demographics">
    {%crispy frm%}
</form>
<form class="tab-pane fade" id="diagnosis" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="diagnosis">
    {%crispy frm_d%}
</form>
<form class="tab-pane fade" id="a_b_sickle" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="a_b_sickle">
    {%crispy frm_a_b_s%}
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def input(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        submitted = request.POST.get('form_id', '')
        print submitted

        if submitted == 'demographics':
            # Get the Form1 instance
            my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST)
            #my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm()

            if my_demographics.is_valid():
                my_demographics_object= my_demographics.save()
                my_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm({'patient': my_demographics_object.patient_id, 'diagnosis_option': 'b-thalassaemia syndromes'})
                my_a_b_sickle=A_b_sickle_thalForm({'patient': my_demographics_object.patient_id})
            else:
                my_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm()
                my_a_b_sickle = A_b_sickle_thalForm()


        elif submitted == 'diagnosis':
            my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST)
            my_demographics = DemographicForm()
            my_a_b_sickle = A_b_sickle_thalForm()
            if my_diagnosis.is_valid():
                my_diagnosis_object=my_diagnosis.save()
                my_a_b_sickle =A_b_sickle_thalForm({'patient': my_diagnosis_object.patient})

            else:
                my_demographics = DemographicForm()
                my_a_b_sickle = A_b_sickle_thalForm()

        elif submitted == 'a_b_sickle':
            my_a_b_sickle = A_b_sickle_thalForm(request.POST)
            my_demographics = DemographicForm()
            my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm()

            if my_a_b_sickle.is_valid():
                my_a_b_sickle.save()

        else:
            raise ValueError('No form specified !')
    else:
        my_demographics = DemographicForm()
        my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm()
        my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm()

return render(request,'input.html', {'frm':my_demographics, 'frm_d': my_diagnosis, 'frm_a_b_s': my_a_b_sickle})
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You can either submit them using ajax or send them back filled in your context. If you can get the saved objects between request by any association they have you can try:

For the second way you can try something like this:

```
my_demographics = DemographicForm(my_demographic_object)
my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(my_diagnosis_object)
my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm(my_a_b_sickle)

return render(request,'input.html', {'frm':my_demographics, 'frm_d': my_diagnosis, 'frm_a_b_s': my_a_b_sickle})
```

In fact, with that you can even make that work as an update form with a little extra using the 'instance' attribute of ModelForm.

Comment: @cdbvv7788 In which place in my code do I have to have to input the code you posted? The objects are only available when the corresponding `submitted` is enabled.

Comment: Also, if I'll have filled my forms, if I press the submit button on the second form, I don't want to save the values of the first button again (because I saved them earlier). I just need to show them.

Comment: You are somehow detecting which form is being submitted, just save the data for the submitted object. About where it should be...you need you context to contain something like that, you need to replace all the forms initialized with empty values where they have an object already